# Rails, Content Compression via Rack::Deflater

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, gzip

I'm trying to serve my HTML, CSS and JS compressed as a gzip with my Rails 5 app, but I can't get it to work.

I've added below code to my `application.rb` but `Html` output is same(not compressed).

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
```

By the way, I use nginx and passenger. What else should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gem for that. You can add this Gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'htmlcompressor', '~> 0.4.0'
```

And add this line to your `application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use HtmlCompressor::Rack
```

I'm using this inside a Rails 6 application and it worked out of the box.